# MathJax Library Leaving Scroll Bars in Formulae

Tags: javascript, html, math, mathjax

I've been trying to use MathJax to create some math tools to use for my A-Levels, I am currently making a page for quadratics and a small calculator for roots of a quadratic equation.

My problem comes when I tried to display a formula using MathJax, as you can see here (http://www.lucapassariello.co.uk/mathsTools/quadratics), what is displayed is a mess of scroll icons, and when the correct formula does display for a short amount of time, everything seems to be raised as a power of nothing.

Below is the link used to the library and a config script.

```
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]}
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

And here is the implemented HTML of the quadratic formula.

```
<p>$$x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}$$</p>
```

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided works as intended, so I assumed it had to be something with your site.

If you **remove** `overflow-x: hidden;` from the below code in the `resources/public/css/style.css` file then you will be back to working. It seems to be conflicting with the Mathjax css and cutting off elements that are rendered from the script.

If you still need the `overflow-x: hidden` then I would suggest being more selective with it instead of using `*`

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```